# Is_dir не видит папки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

В директории есть более 1000 папок. Из них функция `is_dir` видит только 21. Если воспользоваться `!is_file`, то все что в папке будет не файлами (так и есть). Так же функция opendir не открывает папки, которые не видит `is_dir`. По какой причине такое может происходить?

Comment: может permissions? Какую-то ошибку выбрасывает? E_WARNING?

Answer (score 1):

E_WARNING думаю отключенно включите